# Which of these is the better architecture/design approach?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, architecture, dependency-injection

> **Objective**
>   To write a effecient Active Directory library to ease the work of technicals who are responsible to create access models into the domain controller's Active Directory. This library must allow the following:

1. Basic operations: Add, Modify, Delete, List entries;
2. An entry may either be an organizational unit, group or user (no further need required as of now);

I thought about having a class which would represent the domain with which we want to work with.

```
public class Domain {
    public Domain(string root) {
        Root = root;
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, IDirectoryEntry>();
    }

    public string Root { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, IDirectoryEntry> Entries { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, I have used dependency injection to enforce the belonging constraint to a domain of an entry. For example:

```
public abstract class DirectoryEntry : IDirectoryEntry {
    public DirectoryEntry(Domain domain, string name) {
        Domain = domain;
        Name = name;

        Domain.Entries.Add(name, this);
    }

    public Domain { get; private set; }
    public Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationalUnit : DirectoryEntry {
    public OrganizationalUnit(Domain domain, string name)
        : base(domain, name) {
    }
}

public class Group : DirectoryEntry {
    public Group(Domain domain, string name)
        : base(domain, name) {
    }
}
```

Now, notice that I add the entry using `Domain.Entries.Add()` to the given domain upon instantiation of an `IDirectoryEntry` interface.

> **Questions**

1. Is this a good practice, if I don't want the user to change the `Domain` property of any `IDirectoryEntry` instances?
2. Would it be preferable to simply let this `Domain.Entries.Add()` line go away, and have a method within my `Domain` class that would add an entry to the domain?

**Code Sample for question #2**

```
public class Domain {
    //See above for other members.
    public void AddEntry<T>(T entry) {
        Entries.Add(entry.Name, entry);
    }
}
```

---

- **What is, according to you, the best architecture in this situation?**
  Both seem to be good enough to be considered, so I'm a bit confused about it wanting the easiest possible way for the library end-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at .NET 3.5/4's System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace? It provides much of the functionality you require in a more unified and .NET friendly interface. I personally have written a library with similar requirements to yours, using a combination of both.

Overall, I think your design looks good, but I don't know enough about your problem domain to know if you'll be painting yourself into a corner so to speak.

Specifically, to Question 1, I think that will work; however, anyone with a reference to an instance of `Domain` could remove any given Entry.

To Question 2, that is very likely how I would implement it myself, unless I had a compelling reason not to.

Comment: Thank you Nate. Unfortunately, my customer contraints me to use .NET 2.0, otherwise I would have used 3.5. Besides, I am not afraid to be painted into a corner, as I intend to write my code in the more flexible way possible, as you may have noticed. Thus, I am still wondering about this question. In the end, both ways are equivalent, except that if one day I want to detach an entry from the AD, I will have to remove the dependency injection, I guess. Let's say if I want to manage security against an underlying database. Otherwise, I see this dependency injection justified. What do you think?

Comment: I do not see any issue requiring a `Domain` object in the constructor of your other classes; while its tightly coupled, if you migrate off LDAP the concept of a `Security Group` and an `Organizational Unit` will likely go away and be replaced with something else.

Comment: They don't have an issue with you building something that's already in .NET 3.5, but they won't let you use 3.5? That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: This is a nice point you bring there in your answer specific to Q1 when you mention that anyone with a reference to an instance od `Domain` could remove any given Entry. I didn't think of it before. Very interesting! =)

Comment: @OJ: I couldn't agree more! Nevertheless, I might understand their concerns as they are still using Windows 2000. They are just migrating to Vista, that is, because 2000 is no longer supported. I guess then they fear that certain systems won't support .NET 3.5 if they are obliged to update toward. This is a governmental organization, so you might understand all the trouble this might caused is somehow something wouldn't work because of incompatibility reasons. Besides, the organic architect responsible for this choice is very stubborn.